# How to output a vector double? And stop before my integer

Tags: c++, vector, struct, int, double

How to output a vector double? And stop before my integer.
I have a **list of number with variable lenght** say:(!w/ lines)

325 25 25 25 50 255 255 255 255

0.3 0.7

2

And I already taken the number before 0.3 but now I want to keep 0.3 0.7 in a vector but keep 2 as an integer for further uses. I tried with to push value but I dont know how to stop. Because my length of any line can change according to plan. I push everything in a structure for ease of use(maybe?)

```
typedef vector<int> PIXEL;

struct Donnee{
int color;
PIXEL colour;
vector <double> values;
int filter;};
int main{ Donnee Donnee}

void input(Donnee & Donnee){
cin >> Donnee.color;
Donnee.colour = couleur(Donnee.color);//it makes a vector according to size of Donnee.color
cin >> //where I want my double value
cin >> // where I want my int
```

Is there a way without using string and getline or is it necassary here? Thank you and sorry for bad english.

Comment: How did you manage to read the first line of integers and stop before 0.3? Why can't you use the same technique to read the second line and stop before 2?

Comment: Because the length of the line 0.3 and 0.7 can change and I wont know its size that's why I need to test for double and stop before int, the reverse (int ,double) I know how to do it. but I cant here

Comment: Do you really format code the way its shown in your question?

Comment: Use `getline` to read the lines, stuff them in to a `stringstream` and happily fill your `vector`s from there. With `operator>>` its not possible to reliable distinguish between an integer and a floating point number.